# angularCLI Access-Control-Allow-Origin Multiple Origin Domains

Tags: angular-cli, angular2-template, angular2-services

Error>>>> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:60712/api/Default. Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

running ng serve   http://localhost:4200/

Not sure what to do.  I just want to test for local development.

I did the npm install ember-cli-cors
I added Cors to mvc project.
my headers in my angularCli project looks like

let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'false','Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Content-Type' });

```
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this._http.get(this._data, options)
        .map((response: Response) => <any[]>response.json())
         .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error ))//|| this.showError()
            .do(data => console.log('List: ' + JSON.stringify(data)));
```

Comment: CORS is configured on the server side. Whatever you are using to serve the API you are calling will need to be configured to allow this.

Comment: Not sure what you mean @R.Richards  This is an angularcli application with http service from the angular core. Maybe .   example  let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'false','Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Content-Type' });

Comment: I can see what the client side application is. What is being used to run the API that you are calling? What is running localhost:60712? *That* is where the config must change.